Decoding a door key using computer vision by detecting the cuts and grooves
Every single door key is cut using a special code (4-5 digits) that defines the depth of each cut/groove on the key. Keysmiths can usually decipher the code for a key simply by looking at it. I'm working on a project on decoding the keys using a clear, well-lit, flat image of the key.
I have already preprocessed the raw image to get a segmented image of the shoulder of the key that needs to be decoded.
The part I'm having trouble figuring out is:

How to detect where the cuts/grooves are along the shoulder
How to get the depth of the cut by measuring the distance to the other side of the shoulder

I'd love to get some ideas for how to approach this. My idea was maybe to plot the distance between the straight part and the cuts, and look for minima in the graph, but I'd really like a second or third opinion on ideas.
What I've done so far:

Applied image segmentation to the key to make it pop from the background
Automatically cropped out the head of the key (the round part at the top), and the tip of the key at the bottom to get only the part of the shoulder where the grooves exist

I now have a segmented image of the shoulder of the key that needs to be decoded.


The cut depth should be measured at fixed locations between the top and bottom of the image, assuming your processing up to this point is consistent and always grabs the same section of the key. You might not need to detect the measurement locations at all. Or maybe you only need to find out how many there are, and what the offset is if the key could be shifted.

turn the picture on its side. now you've got a graph of a function. now you should figure that finding local extrema might be useful.

@CrisLuengo I'm afraid using fixed locations in the image isn't an option because the scope of the project contains different types of keys, which won't all line up the same even if our formatting is consistent.

@ChristophRackwitz I'm glad you suggested this because that's exactly what I've been trying so far, with middling results. Seeing a fair bit of false positives with detecting minima in the graph, so I'm currently trying to refine that.

The obvious next step is edge detection. You've got two strong edges, on the left and right. The goal would be to detect those. After that, you can turn those two edges in line segments. That gives you coordinates.

I don't think edge detection is useful here. The background is black, it is easy to separate the foreground from the background.

I'm not sure how detecting the biting points and getting their distance to the flat edge on the right would be possible with edge detection, could you explain?

@Cris: There are a few dark spots on the foreground, but those produce much weaker edges, plus they're in the middle.

@AnonymousProgrammer: The idea is to turn those edges into a polygon next, then find the corner points of that polygon.
